# Can I move to another department for a PhD within the same university?

Tags: phd, graduate-school

I'm starting a PhD in Development Studies at a well known university in the UK. I'm considering requesting to be moved to the department for political science. My topic is much better suited to political science than it is for development studies and I believe the former is better suited for the research I intend to do. Both departments are in the same school and my supervisor is a professor in both departments. Do universities consider such requests at all?

Comment: What does your supervisor say?

Comment: I haven't spoken to her yet. I'm not from the UK and I don't know what the norm is. I wanted to know if such requests are entertained at all.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a local question to be answered locally. Rules vary.

Comment: "my supervisor is a professor in both departments" ... Ask your professor!

Comment: If this were my country, people wouldn't take too kindly to this question, which is why I wanted to make sure. Seems like it is okay to ask, then. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest approaching this as "I was wondering if it would be better for me to be based in the Political Science department" rather than "I want to move" - but it is fine to have a conversation with your supervisor. Perhaps think first about why you think a move would be beneficial - it may be possible to achieve the same things without a formal change in department.

Comment: @Avid, thank you for your suggestion, it is most helpful.